# Python get intersection of elements from list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, set

I have a `list` of lists where each list is a `string` of `list` of `int`, as shown below

```
a = ['[11, -12, -14, 13]',
     '[8, 5, -14, 15, 13]',
     '[13, 24, -14]']
```

I need to find a list of common integers (intersection of lists), in this case output should be `[13, -14]`, since they are common in all.

Is there a simple way to do this since the individual lists are `str` type, where I can avoid a first iteration to `eval` and then find `set`?

Comment: It depends on what the syntax of the string is. In your example, those look like python string literals and `ast.literal_eval` would turn it into a python list. You could then use `collections.Counter` to count them. Or maybe `set` depending on what you mean by "common integers".

Comment: I don't think there's a way that doesn't first involve parsing the strings. You can, and probably should, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) rather than eval, but since there is no syntactical information associated with the strings, whatever solution will end up being essentially equivalent to using `literal_eval`.

Comment: By which I mean, you can write your own parsing code, but that doesn't seem simpler than just using the string parsing code that is already in the standard library.

Comment: @tdelaney by common integers I meant the intersection of the lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `map()` the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function over list `b` to safely evaluate your list of strings into a iterator of lists.
2. Then `map()` the `set()` constructor to cast your lists to sets.
3. Finally, use [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with `set.intersection()` to find the intersection of your sets.

```
from functools import reduce
from ast import literal_eval

answer = reduce(set.intersection,    # 3
             map(set,                # 2
             map(literal_eval, a)))  # 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest way of solving it but it works! This will handle any number of lists in A.

```
a = ['[11, -12, -14, 13]',
     '[8, 5, -14, 15, 13]',
     '[13, 24, -14]']

b = []

## this block converts the strings into integers, after this b will be a, but integer lists
for ls in a:
    truncated_str = ls.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
    my_list_of_strs = truncated_str.split(",")
    my_list_of_ints = []
    for num in my_list_of_strs:
        my_list_of_ints.append(int(num))
    
    b.append(my_list_of_ints)
    
## this functions finds commonalites
def in_all_lists(lists, value_to_check):
    
    for my_list in lists:
        if value_to_check not in my_list:
            return False
    return True

common_numbers = []


# checks to see if values are common
for lst in b:

    for value in lst:
        if value not in common_numbers and in_all_lists(b, value):
            common_numbers.append(value)
            
print(common_numbers)  # prints [-14, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Via the `json` library:

```py
import json

l = [set(json.loads(x)) for x in a]

list(l.pop().intersection(*l))
> [-14, 13]
```

### Explanation

`json.loads()` converts the string representation of a list to an actual list. Subsequently, we call `intersection()` on the list of sets. In particular, it is called first on the last element of that list via `pop()`. Then, all sets are passed as arguments into the `intersection()` via unpacking with `*l`. (The fact that the last set technically entered twice won't matter for the output. It just streamlined the code).